# ajax content not loading on ie7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, supersized

it is working on all browsers but ie7 and ie8.
The content dosn't seem to load into the site when we press a menu item while it does work on all major browsers, not sure if it is due to the supersised plugin (?)

I can't get my head around it and I'm kinda stack!

p.s. If it can help anyhow: I am loading the content once supersized animation has finished, you can find this at the end of supersized.shutter.min.js

Any takers please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem being with IE parsing the document was causing this issue. Since I am using wordpress i manage to get around the issue by calling the header and the footer with ajax.

```
<?php if (!is_ajax_request()) get_header(); ?>
  -----
 <?php if (!is_ajax_request()) get_footer(); ?>
```

in my function.php i have:

```
 function is_ajax_request() {
  return (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&            strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
 }
```

Done :)

Answer (score 0):

The error in my firebug is with this line:

```
jQuery(".content").lionbars();
```

maybe enclose it in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".content").lionbars();
}):
```

Comment: mm by completly removing it doens't seem to fix the issue tho

Comment: The other issue is with this line: $(".content").lionbars();

Not sure what it is supposed to do?

Comment: lionbars is a jquery plugin (http://www.nikolaydyankov.com/lionbars/) to replace default scrollbar. It used to work, now it's some css. However, that is not responsable for the issue stated above tho, as nothing changes if i completly remove it :(
Content just doesn't load in ie7 and 8 with ajax

Comment: The issue get is that because of javascript bug there is no ajax call at all to the server.  Not sure if that helps, but maybe since there are errors in the JS (do you remove the lionbars script ref and all the calls to the plugin?)  that cause the ajax Js not to call the server?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".content").each(function(){
     this.lionbars();
 });
```

This would do the trick. refer jquery.min.js above the block where this script is called.

Comment: thing is, if i load the content via ajax and lionbar (the replacement for default scrollbar) is loaded before the content loads, this won't be applied to the loaded content div. In any case, the issue here is about ie7 and ie 8 not loading the content via ajax, i have tried completely removing lionbar plugin and all its calls and that did not solve the issue here :(
Works fine in ff, chrome and ie9 tho. Click menu item, load new content after background changes.

Comment: i have inserted an alert to check if content is loaded in ie7 and ie8 and that doesn't show up which suggests me the content isn't loaded

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem myself. Is the html that gets returned by the ajax call valid html?
If it is not then IE8 and IE7 will not display it (would be nice if they gave an error message but they dont).

One way to confirm whether this is the issue is if you can simplify the ajax content to be something like:

```
<p> hello world</p>
```

If this then starts showing up in IE7/8 then you need to fix the html that your ajax load returns.

Comment: yup. my header and my footer were loading together with the content and it was causing wrong parsing, as you said it'd be nice if it tells you anyhow but it doens't. Eventually managed to solve it by using what answered above. Thanks tho